# multi fields aggregation for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, field, aggregation

Recently I am working on elasticsearch aggregation. I want to classify my data by two fields(`AccountId` and `RestapiId`) to calculate the rate of `ThrottleByApiId`.

My data is like:

```
{
        "AccountId": "12345678909",
        "Marketplace": "us",
        "Operation": "InvokeGet",
        "RestapiId": "ajsdf87238",
        "InvokingPath": "/path/path/path",
        "ThrottleByAccount": 1,
        "ThrottleByApiId": 1
}
```

And I want the result like:(in English)

```
for account=12345678909 and RestapiId= ajsdf87238, the rate of ThrottleByAccount is 1.0(for example).
```

I know both `_copy_to` and script can do this, but I am not sure which one is better. 
Another problem is, I tried to use script. 
My query is like this:

```
{
      'size': 0,
      'query': {
          'filtered': {
              'query': {
                  'match_all': {}
              },
              'filter': {
                  'range': {
                      'StartTime': {'gte': 1467579710,
                                    'lte': 1467579730
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      },
      'aggs': {
          'rateByAccount': {
              'terms': {
                  "script": "[doc.AccountId.value, doc.apiId.value].join(\"-\")"
              },
              'aggs': {
                  'ThrottleByApiId_Rate': {'avg': {'field': 'ThrottleByApiId'}}
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

For the syntax in "script", except the above one, I also tried:

```
"script": "doc['AccountId'].value" + " | " + "doc['RestapiId'].value"
```

and

```
"script": "doc['AccountId']" + " | " + "doc['RestapiId']"
```

and

```
"script": "doc['AccountId'] + doc['RestapiId']"
```

But anyone won't work.
I get this error:

```
File "search_eg.py", line 102, in search_fieldsss
    'ThrottleByApiId_Rate': {'avg': {'field': 'ThrottleByApiId'}}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 548, in search
    doc_type, '_search'), params=params, body=body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 329, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 109, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 108, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: <exception str() failed>
```

In the error message, it is said something wrong with 
'ThrottleByApiId_Rate': {'avg': {'field': 'ThrottleByApiId'}}.
But I've tried replacing script aggregation with direct field aggregation like this:

```
'aggs': {
          'rateByAccount': {
              'terms': {'field': 'AccountId'},
              'aggs': {
                  'ThrottleByApiId_Rate': {'avg': {'field': 'ThrottleByApiId'}}
              }
          }
      }
```

it works fine. So I don't think the error message is accurate. There is something wrong with the script syntax, not the average calculation syntax.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: The error complains about `ThrottleByAccount` which I don't see in your query. Can you make sure your question faithfully reflects what you're doing?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed it up since I have many queries. Just replace 'ThrottleByApiId'  with 'ThrottleByAccount', this is a typo.The right aggregation query with errors is(for the syntax in average aggregation):
'aggs': {
                  'ThrottleByApiId_Rate': {'avg': {'field': 'ThrottleByAccount'}}
              }.
While I've tried one field by replacing:
'terms': {
                "script": "[doc.AccountId.value, doc.apiId.value].join(\"-\")"
              }
with
'terms': {
                'field': 'AccountId'
                    }
Which works well. Only after using script, it failed.

Comment: I suggest you update your question and fix the typos as it will make it easier to know where we're at. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! And I've updated the question above.

Comment: Can you show your code in `search_eg.py`around line 102 ?